# What happens (on Linux) if two programs open the same file for writing ("w+") and start writing?

Tags: file, file-io

I've had this question for a long time.

Let's say at time `t=0 sec` program `A` opens file `/data` with `"w+"` flags. It wipes out `/data` clean and starts writing data to this file.

Now let's say at time `t=1 sec` program `B` opens the same file `/data` with `"w+"` flags and starts writing data to this file.  What the heck happens now?

Program `B` aparently wipes `/data` clean and starts writing at the beginning, while program `A` has advanced and has a file position pointer pointing somewhere into the file.

What the heck happens at this moment? How does operating system know what the contents of the file is going to be?

Let's say `B` writes 100 bytes of `bbbbbbbbbbbb...` While `A` keeps writing lots of `a` letters `aaaaaaaaa...`

What is going to happen to the file?

Is it going to be like:

```
 `bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb[100 b's] ??? what is happening here ??  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...`
```

Is there going to be empty space between `b`'s and `a`'s? What is this empty space? It's not going to be space characters because no program wrote space characters. So what are empty spaces in file?

Overall what is going to happen? Does anyone know. I'm so puzzled my head is hurting.

Comment: You can write your own code and find out for your self

Answer (score 1):

So here's some node.js - we start writing an `a` every millisecond and then write a `b` and quit after 100ms:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const w1 = fs.createWriteStream('test', {flags: 'w+'});
const w2 = fs.createWriteStream('test', {flags: 'w+'});

setInterval(function writerA() {
  w1.write('a');
}, 1);

setTimeout(function () {
  //setInterval(function writerB() {
    w2.write('b');
  //}, 1);
}, 100);

setTimeout(function stop() {
  w1.close();
  w2.close();
  process.exit();
}, 100);
```

Using 'w+' or 'w' makes no difference to what is written as the '+' just allows you to read from the same handle. The result I get is:

`baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...`

so when the second file is opened for writing, the kernel doesn't truncate the file due to it being open, and instead just starts overwriting from the beginning.